# Is there a way to save ajax data as an integer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from a PHP page with ajax and then store it in a variable used for a while loop.

I have used the data to output the number on the screen so I know it is working however when using the variable for a while loop it's not working.

```
function viewl(){
    var counter = 1;
    var amount = null;
    $.ajax({
    url: 'amountl.php',
    success: function(data){
        amount = parseInt(data);

    while(counter <= amount){

    var name = "";
    var cost = "";
    var archetype = "";
    var rarity = "";
    var ability = "";
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {name: name, cost: cost, archetype: archetype, rarity: rarity, ability: ability},
    url: 'viewl.php',
    success: function(value){});
        counter++;
}}})}
```

Some of the code is still left out because it is too much and the site won't let me post it all.

Comment: ajax is async, it execute while loop don't wait `amount = data`, you should try callback, or add `async: false` to your `$.ajax`. You can reference this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: In the first `success` What does `console.log(data)` display?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 10</body>
</html>

Comment: @lighter when i do that i get an error in the console that says 'XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.'

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to count how many request do you do? Or maybe you want to get all the views and put them onto the page?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PHP code is trying to return an HTML document, hence you cannot read the value as is. In `viewl.php`, you should try to return the response in JSON format.

```
<?php
// amountl.php
$data = array( "amount" => 5 );
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
// json_encode will convert the array to { "amount" : 5 }
```

Then in our Javascript code, modify the success function.

```
...
url: 'amountl.php',
dataType: 'json',
success: function( data ) {
    amount = parseInt( data.amount );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Still doesnt seem to work, for some added context i am trying to return a variable $sum from a php page which gets the sum of the qty of items in a table.